# How to make string accessible to all forms?

Tags: c#, string, listview, global

I have a form called **AddFile.cs** and I have a textbox `tbPassword` and button `btnOkay` in it. What Im trying to do is (on  a click of a button) make the text of this textbox a string so I can use it across all forms and add it in `ListView`, so it displays the text written in `tbPassword` in `ListView`.

Comment: "accessible to all forms" sounds like you haven't learned a lot about c#. Try some tutorials first. BTW, why would you like to show the password in other forms?

Comment: do a google search on C# .net tutorials also start reading and learning the basics here.. http://www.dotnetperls.com/ and you never want to expose passwords.. this is `BAD PRACTICE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a public method in your `Form` class and call that to get the result:

```
public string GetPassword()
{
  return tbPassword.Text;
}
```

So then, when you have shown your dialog you can call that to get the result:

```
AddFile addFileForm = new AddFile();
addFileForm.ShowDialog();
string password = addFileForm.GetPassword();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a public static string variable inside a public static class to store something like this to make it accessible to all forms

Answer (score 0):

If you want global access across all the application without having the instance of the form you can use an static property:

```
public static string Password{ get; set; }
```

Then assing the value to that property and you can use anywhere something like this:

```
string pass = MyFormClass.Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is nice to have some global info stored in an app.

One easy way to do this would be to have a public static class named eg. Global in the global namespace oh your default root namespace and in there you can have static properties of the data you need to persist.

However I have to say that as others have pointed out storing a password needs special care and try to avoid it whenever possible.